# How to use embed_content hook?

Tags: hooks, the-content, documentation

From [the document](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_content) of `embed_content`:

> Prints additional content after the embed excerpt.

But I don't know which content it will print. Does it take any arguments?

Comment: No, the hook doesn't pass any arguments to the hook's callbacks. And you can use that hook to display something after the embed excerpt is displayed.

Comment: @SallyCJ Do you have examples? I quite don't understand the 'embed excerpt'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WordPress does not pass any arguments to the hook's callbacks. And you can use that hook to display something after the [embed excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt_embed/) is displayed. But this is of course, if the theme is using the default embed template for post embeds — with custom template, you could, if you want to, display the entire post content.

And the embed excerpt is really an [automatic or manual excerpt](https://wordpress.org/support/article/excerpt/) of the content of the embedded post — see examples below.

**Code Sample**

```php
// No arguments passed to this callback.
function my_callback() {
    // Here, you can use the_xx functions like the_ID().
    echo '<p><b>This is the additional content.</b></p>';
}
add_action( 'embed_content', 'my_callback' );
```

**Preview 1: Embedding a post having an *auto-generated* excerpt**

[image]

**Preview 2: Embedding a post having a *defined/manual* excerpt**

[image]

So in both previews, the "This is the additional content." was added via the `embed_content` hook.

Comment: This answer should be add to Wordpress codex.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. :)